# Geolocation-WatchPosition is not yet implemented

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation

i am using react-native-geolocation-service to get location.
getting current location without any issue and my current location is moving updating fine. but watchId is always udefined and show me a warning of "WatchPosition is not yet implemented". neither it is showing any error
this is i am doing in componenetDidMount

```
this.watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {      
       console.log("position")       
       },
      (error)=>{
       console.log(error  }            ,
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0, 
       distanceFilter: 
         3 }    
      );


     Is there any idea to solve it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i used react native version for getting watchPosition

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(   (position) => {
console.log(position)
}))
```

it is working fine for me.